# How to do border detection in shading?

Tags: node-editor, edges, shader-nodes, vector

I want to create a node setup such that I can detect the border of a 2d shape. Below is the image of the 2D floor I have for a room. I want to detect the border of this floor. I've tried to use the method of taking the dot product of the bevel and normal nodes, but this doesn't do it.
[image]

Does anyone know how I can do this?

Comment: Sorry, your question is a bit unclear - you are asking about a 2D object, but in your image, you show the "bottom" faces of a 3D object (that may or may not be beveled - hard to tell) - Do you mean you want to edge detect (border detect) only on the bottom faces (or any particular selection) of of 3D objects?

Comment: Yes, thats exactly what I want. Sorry for not being clearer.

Comment: I'll look into it, but I should warn you - edge detection isn't exactly a "flushed out feature" in blender from my experience - it often produces as many headaches as it does good results ;)

Comment: Thank you! I'll keep that in mind and try not to delve into it too much.